# Restrict Email Delete Access in Outlook Using Group Policy

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, outlook

Is there a way to restrict users from deleting email from Outlook using Group Policy or some other setup?

Or else is there any email client or provider having functionality such that admin can restrict users from deleting the emails?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Exchange, you should read up on [Messaging Records Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mrm/mrm?view=exchserver-2019). Combine retention policies and litigation hold policies for the desired effect. This can also be done in O365. License requirements apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Will try it @Mikael

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm something listed below:

1. What is the version of your exchange server?
2. Which user does you want to restrict? Mailbox owner or mailbox
   delegate?

If you want to restrict mailbox owner from deleting items, you could refer to the [blog](https://www.slashadmin.co.uk/office365-how-to-prevent-users-from-permanently-deleting-email-aka-litigation-hold/) to prevent users from permanently deleting email,  here are some detailed step for your reference.

If you want to restrict mailbox delegate from deleting items, only assign mailbox folder permission to these delegates, running the following command to assign permssion:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user01@contoso.com:\inbox -User delegate@contoso.com -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Explanation on folder permission: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps#parameters